# Hide MasterViewController when the cells are clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I have a Master Detail View ipad application. I want to close/hide the `masterViewController` when I click on the cells and load something. I am loading a separate view controller on `DetailViewController` when I click on the table cell. It works perfectly fine when I am not loading another View on `detailView`. What can I do to close the `masterViewController` once I click the table row.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    [_detailViewController.navigationController pushViewController:[self.storyboard     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ABCViewController"] animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the way for this. If someone would need this answer here it is:

Get Register for notification on you detail view.

1)On your detail view get register for notification.

- (void) viewDidLoad

  {

  ```
  //for showing loginview
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  
  selector:@selector(dismissPop) name:@"MASTERROWSELECTED" object:nil];
  ```

  } 
  2)On your master view on didSelectRowAtIndexPath do this;
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {

  ```
   //do normal things you usually do

  //post notification that row is selected and you need to dismiss popover.

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MASTERROWSELECTED" 
   object:nil];
  ```

  }
  3) write this method on your detail view.
- (void)dismissPop
  {

  if(self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {

  ```
       //self.popover is your reference to master view pop 
       if([self.popover isPopoverVisible])
       {
           [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
       }
  ```

  }

}